# Handle with unexpected exception (Python/Jenkins/Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins

I've got little problem connected with Selenium in Jenkins. Sometimes I can see exception like:

'Exception: ERROR Server Exception: sessionId dee6bc0f2b08490ead1e705389ba53ed doesn't exist; perhaps this session was already stopped?'

I'm using Python unittest and selenium to execute my tests. Is it possible to ignore just this one error and has test passed though this error appear?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is occurring in your code, you can use a simple `try: except:`

So

```
try:
    bad_function_that_causes_exception()
except:
    print 'exception occurred in bad function, carrying on'
```

More information [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).